# numpy.savetxt format specifier for array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, format

I'm using `numpy.savetxt` to save my matrix of `dtype=[('time','S8'),('channels', 'float16', 2)]`
A row of this matrix looks like:

```
(b'12:31:24', [ 1.20019531,  4.        ])
```

Is there any way to specify this format? I was trying to use `fmt='%s %.3f %.3f'` but it's not working. `numpy.savetxt` requires pythonic format specifier, not numpy dtype and I can't figure out how to specify array.

If I use different `dtype=[('time','S8'),('channel0', 'float16'),('channel1', 'float16')]` everything works fine, since I get rid of this array and get only columns with floats but I would like to use the dtype with one string and array per row (there are more channels in my device and having data stored in an array simplifies iterating)

Comment: `savetxt` formats each row of the array with `fmt%tuple(row)`.  So `%s %s` should work but will include the [].  Otherwise this dtype can't be handled directly.  You'll have transform the dtype or write your own text writer.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll save it as string and write some converting function to change the format after loading from a file so I get format I want, hoped it can be done in some fancy way...

Comment: `genfrontxt` can use your fancy dtype on a 'flat' csv.

Answer (score 0):

`genfromtxt` can use either of your dtypes on the same text:

```
In [629]: txt = b"1,2,3\n4,5,6"
In [630]: dt=[('time','S8'),('channels', 'float16', 2)]
In [631]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=dt)
Out[631]: 
array([(b'1', [ 2.,  3.]), (b'4', [ 5.,  6.])],
      dtype=[('time', 'S8'), ('channels', '<f2', (2,))])

In [632]: dt2=[('time','S8'),('channel0', 'float16'),('channel1', 'float16')]
In [633]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=dt2)
Out[633]: 
array([(b'1',  2.,  3.), (b'4',  5.,  6.)],
      dtype=[('time', 'S8'), ('channel0', '<f2'), ('channel1', '<f2')])
```

---

`view` can convert between the two dtypes, since the data buffer layout is the same.  So you could write a 'flat' file with

```
In [638]: data
Out[638]: 
array([(b'1', [ 2.,  3.]), (b'4', [ 5.,  6.])],
      dtype=[('time', 'S8'), ('channels', '<f2', (2,))])
In [639]: data.view(dt2)
Out[639]: 
array([(b'1',  2.,  3.), (b'4',  5.,  6.)],
      dtype=[('time', 'S8'), ('channel0', '<f2'), ('channel1', '<f2')])
In [640]: np.savetxt('foo', data.view(dt2), fmt='%s %.3f %.3f')
In [641]: cat foo
b'1' 2.000 3.000
b'4' 5.000 6.000

In [642]: data = np.genfromtxt('foo',dtype=dt)
In [643]: data
Out[643]: 
array([(b"b'1'", [ 2.,  3.]), (b"b'4'", [ 5.,  6.])],
      dtype=[('time', 'S8'), ('channels', '<f2', (2,))])
In [644]:
```